# What are the steps when an HTML form is submitted using POST method?

Tags: html, http, webforms

What are the underlying steps of data transmission when a user submits a HTML form using POST method ?

I searched for the answer but mostly it's been talked about the difference between the POST method and the GET method and where to use them.

The simple answer is that all the data of the form is encoded into byte array and put within the message body of a HTTP request. But, it's too general. I'd like to know the specific steps.

Comment: This is probably better suited for the Programmers Exchange

Comment: I usually just wait for the page to load

Comment: The question is too broad. Good answers would be too long for SO format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Note that the topic is covered in HTML specifications in some detail, and there are several cases, e.g. depending on the `enctype` attribute value.

Comment: @AMR Apparently not: Programmers [just migrated an exact duplicate of this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391043/what-are-the-steps-when-an-html-form-is-submitted-using-post-method) to SO. It's probably just not a good fit anywhere on SE, because it is way to broad (i.e., it seems to be asking for the entire step-by-step instructions in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0)).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring what the server decides to do with the data, no, not really.

The format of the encoded data is determined by the `content-type` specified in the form tag, and defaults to pretty much the same as what would be after the "?" in the URL that would've been build if you used `method="GET"` (see the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type))

Answer (score 0):

The specific steps that are made are related to sending an HTTP request, not to the method which is used (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/OPTIONS/HEAD).

There are differences between POST and GET - but those differences are mainly due to  conventions: Let's take REST web-services for example, GET is used (by convention) to get a resource, while POST is used to CREATE a resource and PUT - to modify an existing one.

There are also some limitation differences, but again - these limitation exist due to implementations, for example:
IE can hold only 2048 characters in the URL, Tomcat Apache supports up to 4000 characters - so GET requests which are made from a browser are limited, while POST request aren't.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around?

POST - for modifying/updating
PUT - for creating a new resource

Comment: @Hariprasad what's the other way around ?

Comment: Here's a trustable link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Comment: @Hariprasad no it's not the other way around. But since there are browsers that don't support PUT - most of the web-services will support (implement) both PUT and POST for updates. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs